# Declared var vs string performance in JS

Tags: javascript, performance

Just a quickie: while it's much more semantic to write code like:

```
var b   = 'lorem';
var f   = 'ipsum';

for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
    b   = b + f;
}
```

I wonder how much of an overhead having a declared `var` puts on JS's performance, for example, as oppose to (a messier IMHO):

```
var b   = 'lorem';

for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
    b   = b + 'ipsum';
}
```

This is only a small example, but am trying to think about how this could affect a huge codebase of a large app, has anyone got any insight or performance data to hand?

Answer (score 0):

As there is no common Javascript-Interpreter, but many different that may be different from implementation to implementation. For all performance-questions: The best thing is to measure it. Take the time before and after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that with most modern JS interpreters difference should be from negligible to none (considering that variable f is always local, with no complex computations).
I suspect that modern JS interpreters (at least browser based) would analyse the code first. I don't really expect them to "compile" the code to get exact results (too complex), but some level of optimization should be introduced, hence the negligible difference in performance.
With more complex example, where string is generated in some more complex fashion, the difference should be in favor of string literal.

Here i'm taking assumption that modern JS interpreters always have time to analyse the code and introduce some "cheap" optimizations to code

Comment: As Mnementh noted this should vary from implementation to implementation

Comment: Why do you think (and the question imply) that a literal should be faster?

Comment: @katspaugh because string literal might be "compiled" into something like "append /string/". And variable lookup most probably would translate into lookup AND append

Comment: What about memory consumption and GC overhead?